# flash removeMovieClip ALL

Tags: flash

I want to remove all movieclips in my `wrapper` movieclip.

`wrapper.removeMovieClip(ALL CONTENT);`

how can I achieve that ?

Let add, that I don't know names / id of all the movieclips in `wrapper`.
Just want to PURGE all content.  and prepare for futher use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(wrapper.numChildren > 0)
  wrapper.removeChildAt(0);
```

EDIT: Here is a faster version that calls `numChildren` only once.

```
for(var i:Number = wrapper.numChildren; i > 0; i--)
  wrapper.removeChildAt(0);
```